# Chaining multiple ajax calls with Q.js and handling error centrally

Tags: javascript, q, deferred

I would like to chain multiple ajax calls and handle the error (log to a database) if any of those calls fail.

My code for ajax calls is like this:

```
var ajaxCalls = {
        /// <summary>
        /// Register ajaxCalls here
        /// </summary>
        //Get all bridge codes
        getBridgeCode: function () {
            var deferred = q.defer();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: window.routeDictionary.codeTable.GetBridgeCode,
                    type: 'GET',
                    }).then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    delete jqXHR.then; // treat xhr as a non-promise
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }, function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    delete jqXHR.then; // treat xhr as a non-promise
                    helperPlugins.removeWait();
                    deferred.reject(new Error(jqXHR));
                });
                return deferred.promise;
        },
        getRouteCode: function () {
            var deferred = q.defer();
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: window.routeDictionary.codeTable.GetRouteCode,
                type: 'GET',
            }).then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                delete jqXHR.then; // treat xhr as a non-promise
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }, function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                delete jqXHR.then; // treat xhr as a non-promise
                helperPlugins.removeWait();
                deferred.reject(new Error(jqXHR));
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        getOtherCode: function () {
            var deferred = q.defer();
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: window.routeDictionary.codeTable.GetOtherCode,
                type: 'GET',
            }).then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                delete jqXHR.then; // treat xhr as a non-promise
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }, function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                delete jqXHR.then; // treat xhr as a non-promise
                helperPlugins.removeWait();
                deferred.reject(new Error(jqXHR));
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
    }
```

My method for calling the ajax calls is like this:

```
 helperPlugins.showWait('Getting Bridge Codes');
    ajaxCalls.getBridgeCode().then(function(value) {
        helperPlugins.showWait('Getting Route Codes');
        ajaxCalls.getRouteCode().then(function (value) {
            helperPlugins.showWait('Getting Other Codes');
            ajaxCalls.getOtherCode().then(function (value) {
            helperPlugins.removeWait();
         }).fail(function(error) {
            return "Not Found";
        }).then(console.log);
    });
});
```

The functions getRouteCode and getOtherCode will fail because the controllers do not exist. I am able to reach   `deferred.reject(new Error(jqXHR));`
on getRouteCode but nothing after that.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why `jQuery.ajax()` and not Angular's `$http()`?

Comment: This is a jquery project. I dont have an option to go with Angular. This question is about the q promise library https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Doh! Sorry, my mistake, I mistakenly understood Angular's $q, instead of Q.js. An uppercase "Q" would avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have edited my question.